# Divide a pandas dataframe by the sum of its index column and row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, data-cleaning

Here is what I currently have:

```
    print(df)

    10   25  26
10  530  1   46  
25  1    61  61
26  46   61  330
```

How can i transform this to df1 so that we divide each element in the row by the sum of the index columns? The output of df1 should look like this:

```
df1:


    10             25               26
10  530/(530)     1/(530+61)       46/(530+330)  
25  1/(61+530)    61/(61)          61/(61+330)
26  46/(330+530)  61/(330+61)      330/(330)

    print(df1)

    10      25        26
10  1       0.0016    0.0534
25  0.0016  1         0.1560
26  0.0534  0.1560    1
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you're doing but you're not dividing by index columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
a = np.diag(df)[None, :]
b = np.diag(df)[:, None]

c = a+b
np.fill_diagonal(c, np.diag(df))

df_out = df.div(c)
df_out
```

Output:

```
          10        25        26
10  1.000000  0.001692  0.053488
25  0.001692  1.000000  0.156010
26  0.053488  0.156010  1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the solution but you have to change your columns and indexes.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({530: [530, 1, 46],
                   61: [1, 61, 61],
                   330: [46, 61, 330]},
index = [530, 61, 330])

for i in range(len(df)):
   for j in range(len(df)):
      if i == j:
         df.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i, j] / df.index[i]
      else:
         df.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i,j] / (df.index[i] + df.columns[j])
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the rows by the max in the column to reproduce your example.

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(
{
    "column1": df['10'].divide(df['10'].max()),
    "column2": df['25'].divide(df['25'].max()),
    "column3": df['26'].divide(df['26'].max())
}

)
```